# PHP array search - How to find the match of the key of an array in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

How can I find the match of the **key** of an array in **another** array?

For instance,

array 1,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 4 // the lookup key
            [count] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 5 // the lookup key
            [count] => 2
        )

)
```

array 2,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
            [parent_id] => 4 // the match 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
            [parent_id] => 5 // the match 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
        )
)
```

result that I am after,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
            [parent_id] => 4
            [count] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [router] => xxx
            [path] => xxx
            [plugin] => xxx
            [parent_id] => 5
            [count] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Turn array 1 into an associative array where the parent ID is the key. Then loop through array 2 adding the corresponding count to each element.

Comment: thanks. I can imagine how this part can be done - `Turn array 1 into an associative array where the parent ID is the key.` but not sure about the second part - `...adding the corresponding count to each element.` can you show an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

The array_column function will return the parent_id from the second array, the array_search function will match the two parent_ids from array1 and array2, and the array_merge function will merge the two arrays with the matching parent_ids.

Untested, so excuse any small syntax errors.

```
$array1 = array(); // this is your first array in your example
$array2 = array(); // this is your second array in your example
$result = array(); // this is what you're looking for

foreach ($array1 as $row) {
  $result[] = array_merge($row, $array2[array_search($row["parent_id"], array_column($array2,"parent_id")];
}
```